# element.queryselector not showing in Vim

Tags: javascript, vim

Using various javascript-syntax for Vim, but for some reason element.queryselector() and element.queryselectorAll() don't seem to be visible from my omni-completion. Here are my list of javascript syntax libraries.

```
NeoBundle 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
NeoBundle 'isRuslan/vim-es6'
NeoBundle 'othree/yajs.vim'
NeoBundle 'nikvdp/ejs-syntax'
```

Any ideas? Could there be a conflict between the various syntax libraries?

Comment: Well, did you grep those plugins for `querySelector`?

Comment: Yep, its there in yajs.vim.
https://github.com/othree/yajs.vim/blob/master/data/dom-document.yml#L105

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the four listed plugins includes any omni-completion script; therefore they are not responsible for the lack of `queryselector` and `queryselectorAll` in omni-completion suggestions.

Your problem is that the default omni-completion script is pretty old and doesn't have those two methods so you'll need a more up-to-date third party script.

[This one](https://github.com/1995eaton/vim-better-javascript-completion) works very well for me.

Comment: Not sure if there was something I missed, but this doesn't seem to do it either.